# How to root Huawei Honor Bee?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I need help with rooting my new honor bee, I have tried all methods, but none of them work inshort doesn't support my phone, I need help inorder to be able to connect to internet using cable.

Comment: Could you list all those methods, so that an answerer could possibly avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try kingoroot or genius root. I own an non famous brand android phone and I managed to root it with kingoroot. So, I guess this solution may apply to you!

Comment: I tried kingoroot it isn't able to root my phone, and I tried genius root too, it can't root my device too.

Comment: Did you enable usb debugging??? Did you also try root kit???

Comment: I did tried usb debugging, but I don't know about root kit, so any clues?

Comment: No... but probably it worths a tru

Comment: ok, I will do it asap.